# How to make use of .net Standard 2 IFormFile reference in .net Framework 4.7.2 MVC web app

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-5, .net-standard-2.0, .net-4.7.2

We're working to convert a couple of legacy .net framework 4.7.2 web apps to .net core.  We're using the .net standard libraries to allow our infrastructure to be updated before we get the web sites updated.  So, our domain, business and data layers are all .net standard 2 while currently the web sites are .net framework.

In the web sites we have places where the user can upload files.  The viewmodels for the pages previously had these properties defined as an HttpPostedFileBase, but in order to work with .net standard, I had to change them to IFormFile.  But now, when uploading the file I get the model validation error...

```
The parameter conversion from type 'System.Web.HttpPostedFileWrapper' to type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IFormFile' failed because no type converter can convert between these types.
```

Here's the view model code.

```
public class MarketingDocRequestViewModel
{
       public string CompanyName { get; set; }

       public string FirstName {get;set;}

       public string LastName {get;set;}

       public string Address1 { get; set; }

       public string Address2 { get; set; }

       public string City { get; set; }

       public string State { get; set; }

       public string Zip { get; set; }

       public string Phone { get; set; }

       public string Fax { get; set; }

       public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

       public string Website { get; set; }

       public IFormFile LogoFile { get; set; }
}
```

How can I get this working?  I wasn't able to find a way to convert the HttpPostedFileBase to an IFormFile and I also can't find a way to new up an instance of the IFormFile with a stream and other properties.

Comment: Just based on this code can't find the error, You can refer to this [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-7.0) .

Comment: The error is pretty clear - you're using the wrong type, from a completely different stack, ASP.NET Core instead of ASP.NET MVC. You can't convert one to another.

Answer (score -1):

I reproduced this error ,You want to use IFormFile in a asp.net app
[image]

> I wasn't able to find a way to convert the HttpPostedFileBase to an
> IFormFile and I also can't find a way to new up an instance of the
> IFormFile with a stream and other properties.

IFormFile is a interface not class:

[image]

You could try implement the interface:

```
public class FormFile : IFormFile
    {
        public FormFile(string filename,byte[] content)
        {
            FileName = filename;
            Content = content;
        }

        private  byte[] Content {  get; set; }

        public string ContentType => throw new NotImplementedException();

        public string ContentDisposition => throw new NotImplementedException();

        public IHeaderDictionary Headers => throw new NotImplementedException();

        public long Length => throw new NotImplementedException();

        public string Name => throw new NotImplementedException();

        public string FileName { get; private set; }

        public void CopyTo(Stream target)
        {
            var stream = new MemoryStream(Content); 
            stream.CopyTo(target);
        }

        public Task CopyToAsync(Stream target, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public Stream OpenReadStream()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

I tried as below in a asp.net controller:

```
 var memorystream = new MemoryStream();
 HttpContext.Request.Files[0].InputStream.CopyToAsync(memorystream);
 var name = HttpContext.Request.Files[0].FileName;
 var content = memorystream.ToArray();

 //create the instance 
 IFormFile formFile = new FormFile(name, content);
```

Maybe you could have a try :
[image]

[image]